# Why $\sum_yPr\left(Y=y|X=x\right)=1$?

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation

While proving $E\left[E\left[X|Y\right]\right]=E[X]$ I saw use of this $$\sum_yP\left(Y=y|X=x\right)=1$$ but can't comprehend why is it so, please explain? I saw this on wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)

Comment: You can interpret as given that $X=x$, $Y$ can assume some states, say $y_1,\ldots,n_n$. Since these are all the states $Y$ can assume, the probability it assumes one of them is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\sum_yP\left(Y=y|X=x\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow\sum_yP\left(Y=y\wedge X=x\right)=P(X=x)$$