# How to find the variance of X in this case?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let *Y* be an **exponential random variable** with mean $\frac{1}{\theta}$, where $\theta>0$. The **conditional distribution** of *X* given *y* has **Poisson distribution** with mean *y*. Then, what is the variance of *X*.
Edit: pdf of Y is $\theta.e^{-\theta.y}$And pdf of $X|y$ is $\frac{e^{-y}y^x}{x!}$ is it correct, what to do next?The correct solution is one out of the following.

$$1.\frac{1}{\theta^2}\\ 2. \frac{\theta+1}{\theta}\\ 3. \frac{\theta^{2}+1}{\theta^2}\\ 4. \frac{\theta+1}{\theta^2}$$

Comment: Try [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Comment: Thank you so much  @ probablyme I learned this new law today really helpful, I got the answer should I put it here or close the question. One more thing where I can get list of all these important laws related to probability theory.

Comment: No problem. As for a list, I don't know. The two big ones are [total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and [total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Comment: Would you mind giving your opinion on this one http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1613059/263425

Comment: I would say what the first comment says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your work.

You are told that $Y\sim \text{Exp}(\theta)$ and that $X|Y\sim\text{Pois}(Y)$. Notice that $E[X|Y] = Y$, and that $\text{Var}[X|Y] = Y$ since $X|Y$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $Y$.

Thus, by the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), 
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}[X] &= \text{Var}[E[X|Y]]+E[\text{Var}[X|Y]]\\
&=\text{Var}\left[Y\right]+E[Y]\\&=\frac{1}{\theta^2}+\frac{1}{\theta}\\
&=\frac{1+\theta}{\theta^2}.
\end{align*}
So, the answer is (4.)